# How to use the scroll event in Javascript (NO Jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, css

So HERE is the code. I simple want to change the color of the h1 heading when the scroll is 1000px from top. I would like to use purely javascript for this purpose.Please try and ignore how poorly the code has been written. Any suggestion would be more than welcome. Thank you for you time.

```html
<html> <head> <title> scroll </title> 
<!-- CSS !--> 
<style> .redbox { 
background-color: red;
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
height: 90px;
width: 100px;
 } .reveal { 
position: fixed;
top:450px;
transition: width 2s;
display: block;
} </style>
 </head> 
 <!-- HTML !--> 
 <body> 
 <div class='redbox' id='red'> , </div> 
 <h1 class='reveal' id='demo'> The comes up on 1000 scroll! </h1> 
 <h1 style='position: absolute;top: 1900px;'> END </h1> 
 <!-- JS !--> 
 <script> 
 var top = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop 
 if (top == 1000) { 
  document.getElementById('demo').style.color = 'red'}
 </script> </body> </html>
```

Comment: possible to see your code?

Comment: Please provide your code & information about what you have tried. SO is for getting help to resolve a problem that you have tried to resolve yourself, not a place to get code written for you.

Comment: I am really sorry. That was my first Question on stackoverflow. I have made some edits. Thanks.

Comment: ... wait, why can't you use jQuery? ... You should be using jQuery.

Comment: If that is the case then please give me some jquery link or code on how I can achieve the effect. I think i should start learning.I will start learning asap.

Answer (score 2):

You could check the current scroll offset using an event handler:

```
document.body.addEventListener('scroll', function() {

    if(window.scrollY > 499) {
        document.getElementById('myDiv').classList.add('appear'); // or whatever...
    }

});
```